# Php login issue - post version

Tags: php, mysqli

So i have a problem with login in php, i mean it works, but when i reload it says:

> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated.

So i don't really know what to do, this is the code, and if something else is wrong please help me improve it.

PS. I have to use whirlpool because the game script password im using is made in C++ and password is hashed with whirlpool because that is the best hashing plugin there is atm, thanks in advanced.

PS im a newbie in php started 2 days ago and this is what i made:

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();


$db = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$base = "samp";

$konekt = mysqli_connect($db, $user, $password, $base);

if (!$konekt) {
    echo "Konekcija sa bazom nije uspela" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_SESSION["name"]) && $_SESSION["name"] )
{
    echo "Vec ste ulogovani, ".$_SESSION["name"]." <br>Automatski vas odjavljujemo.";
    unset( $_SESSION );
    session_destroy();
    exit;
}   

$UserPrijavljen = false;

$userName = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : null;
$userPass = isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"] : null;

if($userName && $userPass)
{
    $hashedPass = hash('whirlpool', $userPass);
    $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'";
    $result = mysqli_query( $konekt, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row)
    {
        $UserPrijavljen = true;     
    }
    elseif (!$row) {
        echo "Podatci koje ste uneli nisu ispravni, sesija unistena.";
    }
}

if ( !$UserPrijavljen )
{

    echo "
            <form action='index.php' method='post'>
                Korisnicko Ime: <input type='text' name='name' value='$userName'><br>
                Lozinka: <input type='password' name='pass' value='$userPass'><br>
                <input type='submit' value='log in'>
            </form>
        ";
}
else
{
    echo "<div>";
    echo "Prijavljeni ste kao $userName!";
    echo "</div>";
    $_SESSION["name"] = $userName;
}
?>
```

And is there a way when i reload page that it doesnt destroy session and log me out, just to stay logged, this is the part

```
    if(isset($_SESSION["name"]) && $_SESSION["name"] )
{
    echo "Vec ste ulogovani, ".$_SESSION["name"]." <br>Automatski vas odjavljujemo.";
    unset( $_SESSION );
    session_destroy();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Use cookies instead of sessions, it's easier. If you refreshing right after submitting a form, you are probably generating another session.

Comment: it has nothing to do with sessions. you're getting the message because you are refreshing an html form that the browser know was submitted, so its warning you that if you refresh you might send the data again.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you some head start:
Put it on the same page and it should work.
You have to add a session field to your database to keep track of logged users.

```
# logout code
if($_GET['logout']) {
setcookie("login", '',time()-86400); # delete cookie
exit(); # stop executing here
}


# keep user logged in here (add a session field to your database)
if($_COOKIE["login"] && mb_strlen($_COOKIE["login"]) == '32') {

# revalidate cookie (you could use memcached here)
$session = $konekt->real_escape_string($_COOKIE["login"]);
$query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE session = '$session' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query( $konekt, $query); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

# message
if($row['Ime']) { 
echo "User is already logged in with username ".$row['Ime']. " and hash: ".$_COOKIE["login"]. '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
exit(); # don't run the next code below
}


# default login form
echo <<<EOF
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
Korisnicko Ime: <input type='text' name='name' value=''><br>
Lozinka: <input type='password' name='pass' value=''><br>
<input type='submit' value='log in'>
</form>
EOF;


if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['pass']) {
$hashedPass = $konekt->real_escape_string(hash('whirlpool', $_POST['pass']));
$userName = $konekt->real_escape_string($userName);

$query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query( $konekt, $query); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row) { 
$session = md5($userName.$hashedPass); # user unique identifier
mysqli_query($konekt, "UPDATE Igraci SET session = '$session' WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'"); # save to db
setcookie("login", $session,time()+3600); # stay logged in for 1 hour with a unique identifier
echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".$_COOKIE["login"]. '<a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
} else {
echo "Podatci koje ste uneli nisu ispravni, sesija unistena."; # wrong pass?
}
}
```

Comment: Well i dont get this, im using whirlpool and this is md5 is that the same ?

Comment: This is just a code sample for you to understand how it works. I edited the code for the password hash part. As for the cookie, md5 is ok.

Comment: While it's very generous that you did the questioner's work but they won't prosper in their coding endeavours. Stackoverflow isn't for getting your work done but it's for problem solving. Answers should show what they did wrong and what will help. Rewriting code and saying `here use this` is the most unhelpful thing you can do on SO

Comment: I agree, but if he is a beginner I thought that this would give him a starting point. People learn also by looking at working code, and with this code he won't have a fully functional script either way. It just works as an example.